# JS - document.createElement does not work

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code:

```
function icon(link) {
var iccon = document.createElement('div');
var iccons = document.createElement('td');
iccon.setAttribute('id', 'icon');
icons.appendChild(iccons);
iccon.setAttribute('onclick', 'window.open("' + link + '");');
iccons.appendChild(iccon);
var icons = document.getElementById('icons');
};
```

The HTML code is [here](http://codepen.io/bacas/pen/RGBvjW).

Comment: Thanks for showing us your code. How can we help?

Comment: What's your question? What doesn't work exactly? Are you getting an error or unexpected behaviour?

Comment: "The HTML code is" … not in the question, where it should be. You must provide a [mcve]

Comment: At first it's "iccons" but then it's "icons"

Comment: It's working... you are not appending the elements to body, so you can't see them...

Comment: Along with the HTML you're not showing us, I'm betting there's an `Uncaught ReferenceError` you're not showing us too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though it's hard to say what you're trying to achieve with the code, I must say that it's an ordering error: you want to append the newly created items to the `#icons` element, which you declare at the very end.
Move the last statement to the top of the function and everything will work as expected:

```
function icon(link) {
    var icons = document.getElementById('icons');
    var iccon = document.createElement('div');
    var iccons = document.createElement('td');

    iccon.setAttribute('id', 'icon');
    icons.appendChild(iccons);
    iccon.setAttribute('onclick', 'window.open("' + link + '");');
    iccons.appendChild(iccon);
};
```

Here's the updated demo: http://codepen.io/gion/pen/NRmgPJ

I must say that you should be more careful about naming. Things get hard to read when they aren't named well.

Comment: Thanks :) It works.

Comment: Thanks, but could you please delete that pen? You can fork it, if you wanna.

Comment: That pen is already a fork of your original pen.   
I didn't copy-paste everything from one codepen window to another :) . Furthermore, it's intended to help you, not me. Believe me, I have absolutely no intention to use your code rather than a guide for this answer.